# Sourcetree shows huge number of changed files but git command doesn't

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Recently, SourceTree shows a huge number of unchanged files in one repo:

[image]

However, `git status` only shows a few files (see below).  If I add and commit some files from the command line the huge number drops by the corresponding number. But because of the huge number of files, SourceTree is not able to populate the "changed files" sub-window; just spins and spins.

How can I fix this?  I have removed the bookmark in SourceTree and re-added it, but no change.

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   dist/sysetc/php.ini
    modified:   dist/usrlocaltorque/web/be/CTqDatabase.php
    modified:   dist/usrlocaltorque/web/be/dashChunker.php
    modified:   dist/usrlocaltorque/web/js/directives/slider.js
    modified:   dist/usrlocaltorque/web/js/directives/tqDashPlayer.js
    modified:   dist/usrlocaltorque/web/js/pxUIHelpers.js
    modified:   dist/usrlocaltorque/webanalytics/dash/app/lib/controlbar/ControlBar.js
    modified:   ext/README.txt
    modified:   lib3p64/pkgconfig/libavcodec.pc
    modified:   lib3p64/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc
    modified:   packaging/specs/torque-3plib.spec
    modified:   packaging/specs/torque-branding.spec
    modified:   packaging/specs/torque-commonapps.spec
    modified:   packaging/specs/torque-webanalytics.spec
    modified:   src/TqCommon/TqLogger.cpp
    modified:   src/TqMediaProbe/TqMediaProbe.cpp
    modified:   src/cfg/TqCfgParams.cpp
    modified:   src/cfg/TqCfgProcessControl.cpp

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    dist/installers/rescue64/tqRescue64Uefi.img
    dist/sysetc/fonts/
    ext/IntelMediaSDK-gitrepo/
    ext/Simple-WebSocket-Server/
    ext/ac3esbrowser/
    ext/autoconf-2.71/
    ext/libusb-1.0-24/
    ext/libva-utils/
    ext/man/
    ext/tesseractOCR/
    ext/zvbi/
    installRemoteTorqueRsync.php
    lib3p64/pkgconfig/zvbi-0.2.pc
    src/ocr/
```

Comment: _"However, git status only shows a few files (see below)"_ it only shows a few files _and directories_. Those directories likely contain very many untracked files, which accounts for the number you're seeing. If I had to guess, you want to add `/ext/` to `.gitignore`.

Comment: Maybe SourceTree is listing all modified files, while Git is dividing those into tracked and untracked (and is not listing the individual files in the untracked folders).

Comment: Try `git status -u` and you'll find that it also shows huge number of files, changed and untracked.

Comment: @ElpieKay, thanks. `git status -u` indeed did show lots of files and now I know what to add to the `.gitignore` file